# Can I get enum cases as array of values in PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

`Role::cases()` gives me an array of enum objects with name/value pairs.
Example: `case Role = 1;`

Is there any way I can get an array of just all the values? `Array(1, 2, 3)`

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.enumerations.static-methods.php#126866

Comment: Even if this issue got closed, I recommend the solution by u_mulder here in the comments.

Comment: @SeaBass Isn't that the same solution as in the answer on the linked duplicate?

Comment: u_mulders solution wraps it in a method on the enum class, so same idea, but more what I needed.